# Adding up values of nested objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object which contains multiple objects.  Each object has a height and a width, which I need to add together to get a total height and width.  I need to update the totals on input from the user.

Object:

```
$scope.myObj = {
  wall1: {
    wFeet: 0,
    wInches: 0,
    hFeet: 0,
    hInches: 0,
    totalWidth: 0,
    totalHeight: 0
  },
  wall2: {
    wFeet: 0,
    wInches: 0,
    hFeet: 0,
    hInches: 0,
    totalWidth: 0,
    totalHeight: 0
  },
  wall3: {
    wFeet: 0,
    wInches: 0,
    hFeet: 0,
    hInches: 0,
    totalWidth: 0,
    totalHeight: 0
  }
};
```

Right Now I have a function that takes the feet and inches values, converts to decimal feet and adds them up to give the total width and height for each wall.

```
    $scope.setTotalWidthAndHeight = function() {
      angular.forEach($scope.walls, function(wall) {

        //first convert inches to decimal of ft
        angular.forEach(wall, function(dim, dimKey) {

          if(dimKey === 'wInches') {
            wall.wallWidth = wall.wFeet + (0.0833 * dim);
          }

          if(dimKey === 'hInches') {
            wall.wallHeight = wall.hFeet + (0.0833 * dim);
          }

        })
      });
    };
```

What's Im having a problem with now is adding up all the `totalWidth` and `totalHeight` values from each object to get one final width and height for all walls combines.  There has to be a better way to do it than below.

For example:

```
var allTotalWidths = $scope.myObj.wall1.totalWidth + $scope.myObj.wall2.totalWidth + $scope.myObj.wall3.totalWidth;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function can be optimised a little and I'm going to assume where you've currently got `wall.wallWidth =` and `wall.wallHeight =` you meant to have `wall.totalWidth =` and `wall.totalHeight =` as the previous properties don't exist in your example data and will have likely thrown an error.

```
var totalWidths = 0,
    totalHeights = 0;

$scope.setTotalWidthAndHeight = function()
{
    angular.forEach($scope.walls, function(wall)
    {
        wall.totalWidth = wall.wFeet + (0.0833 * wall.wInches);
        wall.totalHeight = wall.hFeet + (0.0833 * wall.hInches);

        totalWidths += wall.totalWidth;
        totalHeights += wall.totalHeight;
    });
};
```

I've altered your function to do all the totalling in one swoop. It will populate the `totalWidth/Height` properties of your initial object and also keep a running total of all widths and heights in the `totalWidths` and `totalHeights` variables.