# Iterate over an array of objects and add values together

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, loops, object

This seems basic but I can't figure it out. I have the following array

```
var myArray = [{a:3, b:4, c:5}, {a:-1, b:3, c:5}, {a:0, b:-3, c:1}];
```

I want to loop through this array and add all the a's,b's,c's together. I want to do it in a loop because I don't know how many objects are inside the array.

Such as:

```
var A = myArray[0].a + myArray[1].a + myArray[2].a;
```

Comment: What should be expected output ?

Comment: You don't know how to write a loop?

Comment: var A = 2, B = 4, C = 11;

Comment: I see loops in your previous questions, and I see [addition of properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615835/adding-up-values-of-nested-objects) of object too. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` and return result for each key in separate variables.

```js
var myArray = [{a:3, b:4, c:5}, {a:-1, b:3, c:5}, {a:0, b:-3, c:1}];
var A = myArray.reduce(function(r, e) {
  return r + e.a;
}, 0)

console.log(A)
```

Or you can use `reduce()` and `Object.keys()` to return sum for each object's property in one variable.

```js
var myArray = [{a:3, b:4, c:5}, {a:-1, b:3, c:5}, {a:0, b:-3, c:1}];
var result = myArray.reduce(function(r, e) {
  Object.keys(e).forEach(function(k) {
    r[k] = (r[k] || 0) + e[k];
  });
  return r;
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you! ````reduce()```` was a great help!

Comment: @user1876246: So you wanted to mutate the first object in the array?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will helps.

```
var sumA = 0, sumB =0, sumC =0;
myArray.forEach(function(v){
  if (v.hasOwnProperty("a") {sumA += v["a"];}
  if (v.hasOwnProperty("b") {sumB += v["b"];}
  if (v.hasOwnProperty("c") {sumC += v["c"];}
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Reduce also works. Just for some taks it's not aceptable

Comment: Oh... except that you have a copy/paste error. Should be `sumB` and `sumC` instead of `sumA` all three times.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry about that :D . Fixed.

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk thanks for your help! I accepted the ````reduce()```` method but this was also very helpful.

Comment: Thank you i agree..Reduce works perfect. Glad you got your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

forEach() could work :

```
var myArray = [{a:3, b:4, c:5}, {a:-1, b:3, c:5}, {a:0, b:-3, c:1}];
var A = 0;
myArray.forEach(x => {A += x.a});
console.log(A); // 2
```

Comment: It *could* work, but it is not the correct functional operation. This is what `reduce` is explicitly made for.

Comment: @meagar: It *does* work. There's no one, correct way to do this. The `.reduce()` method is great, but seriously...

Comment: @squint if you don't have anything nice to say don't say anything at all...

Comment: @user1876246: I just said something nice. This solution *works perfectly*! You think it's nicer to tell someone that their correct solution isn't correct?